# How to have a shell script available everywhere I SSH to

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have a shell script which I simply cannot do without: [bar from Theiling Online](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html)

I use SSH a lot and on a variety of *nix servers. However, I am not a system administrator and usually don't have the time or privileges to install it on every server I connect to.

It is apparently a very portable `sh` script and has command line options to export itself as a shell function, which got me thinking: Could I use one of OpenSSH's subjectively obscure features to export it everywhere I go?

My first thought was to assign the source to an environment variable like `BAR = "cat -v"` and then execute it on the other side as `$BAR`, but 1) I can't even get the cat example to to work locally, 2) I don't know how to put the script's actual multiline source into an environment variable and 3) I have yet to see a machine with `PermitUserEnvironment` enabled.

I guess I could even do with an ssh option to write a file called `~/bar` at logon, but a more volatile solution would be better.

Calling `wget http://.../bar` at logon would be unacceptable.

Any ideas?

P.S. Putty-specific solutions, though I doubt any would exist, are also fine.

Edit: The reason I don't want wget and other file-based solutions is that I don't want to leave a mark since sometimes I connect as other people's users or root. I also don't want every server I connect to making an HTTP request. I want this to have as little overhead as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried any of this, but you may find what you are looking for with a combination of options.

Check out `man 5 ssh_config` for:

1. `SendEnv` - you could store bar into an environment variable, but you then need to execute it. For example `BAR=$(bar -D)`, then in the remote shell `eval $BAR`, having sent the variable over - I know it is one step short of what you want but, hey, progress;
2. `LocalCommand` - not sure that helps, unless you can do an unattended ssh, but then I can't see it working either;

The only other option I see would be to hack into the source code for your client and introduce a feature which executes a command immediately after log-on (such as `eval $BAR` for instance, this could be an `ssh_config` option called `RemoteCommand` for instance), after the environment variables have been sent and before waiting for input from the user.

...

In fact I have an idea for the full answer (untested):

In the `SendEnv`, make sure to send `PS1` and `DEFINEBAR`, and set `PS1` to `eval $DEFINEBAR` ($DEFINEBAR should contain your function and set PS1 to a reasonable value afterwards). The caveat is that the server needs to be configured to accept environment variables, which is unlikely to be the case for a default or secure set-up. So back to square one if your setup does not allow for this.

Comment: All the machines in question seem to have `AcceptEnv = LANG LC_*` which means I might have to use a hack like using `LC_BAR` instead of `BAR`. `LocalCommand` seems to be configured locally and I was able to execute an `echo`, but I don't know how to export an environment variable (or two) from there. `export x=y` didn't work.

Comment: BTW LocalCommand worked exactly like how you thought `RemoteCommand` would.

Comment: @aib, So this means LocalCommand is executed before the shell starts, or as a sub-shell. Bugger. Not sure how to get beyond this. You could probably get LocalCommand to create a file with your script then, can you?

Comment: I see. I was hoping I was doing something wrong, such as not giving the --really-really parameter to export. I guess it has to be a file, then? I'll have to leave a mark on every server I connect to?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on Dennis Williamson's solution that doesn't require that you be able to ssh from the remote machine back to your local machine. On the local system:

```
$ bar -D | ssh user@host 'cat > barfunc'
$ ssh user@host
```

On the remote system:

```
$ . ./barfunc
```

I tested the components of that but not using `bar`, which I don't have.

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you said using wget was unacceptable.   Are you against wget or against copying the file?  I don't think you're going to be able to get the functionality you want unless you somehow copy the file to the local machine.

Maybe you can to source the file (but i'm fairly certain this would fail). The command would like this the following, depending on shell:

```
source mymachine:/home/user/bar
. mymachine:/home/user/bar
```

if you're against wget specifically, you can try scp, with setting up ssh keys it would mean a passwordless experience.

```
mkdir ~/bin; scp -r myserver:/home/user/bin/* ~/bin; chmod u+x ~/bin
```

Personally, what worked for me was to put my shell scripts into a subversion repository and then check out the repo on every machine.   if i updated the script, i can check it back in svn, and then update it on other machines.

Comment: +1 for source control, which I suggested to our sysadmin. Unfortunately, I'm not a sysadmin and the machines may not always have access to our office network where the repository would be stored. It might be a good idea to put my favorite shell scripts on the net somewhere, though, updated via `git` and downloadable through `HTTP`.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you a start:

On your local system:

```
$ bar -D > ~/barfunc
$ ssh user@host     # or similar
```

On the remote system:

```
$ func=$(scp yourname@yoursystem:~/barfunc /dev/stdout)
$ eval "$func"
$ bar_cat somefile ...
```